# bash printf not working - decimals

Tags: linux, bash, floating-point, formatting, decimal

Why did printf didn't WORK for the final command `printf "%s,%.2f\n" "$s","$a"` and what's that extra 0.00 coming from?

When I ran them individually, they worked as expected but not in the final command.

```
$ s="giga,fifa"; a="8309.18694444444444444444"; echo "$s"; printf "%s\n" "$s"; echo -e "\n";  echo "$a"; printf "%.2f\n" "$a"; echo -e "\n"; echo "$s,$a"; printf "%s" "$s,"; printf "%.2f\n" "$a";echo;printf "%s,%.2f\n" "$s","$a"
giga,fifa
giga,fifa


8309.18694444444444444444
8309.19


giga,fifa,8309.18694444444444444444
giga,fifa,8309.19

giga,fifa,8309.18694444444444444444,0.00
```

How can I get this output: `giga,fifa,8309.19` with just one `printf` command showing both variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use a `,` in bash `printf`, you delimit with space. The 0.00 comes from trying to parse the `"$s","$a"` at once, and has odd results - everything is considered one argument and printed as the first string, so no argument exists for the second and a 0 is substituted as default. This works as expected:

```
>printf "%s,%.2f\n" "$s" "$a"
giga,fifa,8309.19
```

Comment: :) oh great! damn comma. That's brings how that `,` impacted this behavior though?

Comment: @ArunSangal Added - you essentially had a single argument. The 0 is a default for the second missing argument.

Comment: Now I know why I added comma, I first looked at BASH's `printf` cmd and then `awk` command's **printf** and got that imprinted in my mind ram, there, I got this error. Thanks.